# 2 USB WiFi adapters, one as a hotspot and the other connecting to a WiFi router

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, network-manager, hot-spot

I am building a remote streaming box with a minimum install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and gnome legacy desktop. This box will be hosting OBS Studio remote controlled. I need one USB Wifi adapter to act as a local network(192.168.250.1) for cameras to connect through while the other USB WiFi adapter is being used to stream out to the internet through the house router(192.168.1.1).

I have finally got the 2 WiFi adapters (wlx7f01=Internet and wlx324e=hotspot/ad-hoc) working independently from each other for the 2 different networks through the graphic network control but they will only work one at a time. When I start one network, it turns off the other. These are 2 different WiFi radios so I should be able to run them like having 2 different Ethernet adapters in the machine. How do I circumvent the network utilities now in control to allow both networks to be on line concurrently?

Also, what would be the better option, hotspot or ad-hoc, for my application since I am using this for another local network and not using NAT although I need to be able to remote access the cameras on this network through this machine from the Router's network?

### Rant & Rave section to ignore:

Ubuntu always has a better idea how to do things so about every 2 years or so, the network strategies and utilities are replaced in favor of their new scheme which makes Ubuntu an OS not for the faint at heart. This makes it impossible to remember where things are and what files are now in play. The most recent change I found is that they dropped the "ifconfig" command which I have been using for over 10 years to look at my network configuration in favor of "ip address" which does about the same thing. I'm getting too old to spend half my time Googling around looking for why my favorite commands no longer work. Why couldn't they just leave the old utility in which everyone was using?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ifconfig.8.html shows ifconfig is still in 18.04 (and 19.10). Yes, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ip.8.html has been added and is preferred, but ifconfig still works.

Comment: Not in the newest 18.04 LTS download. With a minimal install of the desktop, it doesn't work although it is available to install seperatly.

Comment: Then Canonical's documentation is not keeping up with the bits'nbytes. Drat.

Comment: Their changes are coming so fast, that doesn't surprise me.

Comment: I am now trying hostapd/bridge-utils/create_ap and getting configuration error after error.

Comment: Addressing your rant: I recommend using Xubuntu. This will give you ifconfig and other familiar tooling.